# GSA includes the keyword start in the search results when I am searching for restart

Tags: google-search-appliance

I am facing a strange issue with a specific search.

I would expect the below two queries to return the same result set since space between keywords interpreted as AND anyway:

```
1) inurl:taskcracker Angela restart crash

2) inurl:taskcracker Angela AND restart crash
```

First one returns 42 results where the highlighted keywords on the search result page includes 'start' in addition to 'restart'. Whereas the second query returns only 2 results with 'restart' only (no 'start') which what I was expecting from the first search as well.

Please note that it does not matter whether I put an AND in front of other keywords on the 2nd query. It only makes a difference when I put or don't put an AND in front of 'restart'

I initially thought that maybe restart is in the synonyms list under Search > Query Settings > Synonym Data > English in the GSA admin panel but it is not there.

So the issue is when I don't put an explicit AND in front of 'restart' GSA expands it to include 'start' as well.

Any ideas whether this comes from a configuration somewhere on the admin panel or likely to be a bug?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because query expansion doesn't work when you put AND before "restart".

Can you try adding **&entqr=0** to the URL being sent to the GSA? It controls the the query expansion policy. You can also try **&entqrm=0** too if first one doesn't work.